# How to edit docx document and enter equations using Python?

Tags: python-2.7, docx, subscript

I would like to edit `.docx` documents using Python and more importantly I need it to be able to allow me to write subscripts like 2<sub>x</sub> in Python.

I have tried the `docx` module but I can't seem to find out how to write subscripts.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to write subscripts, try using the "stringified" form, so to speak:

```
>>> print '2\xe2\x82\x93'
2ₓ
>>>
```

Comment: ValueError: All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no NULL bytes or control characters (it does not work :()

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XML representation of a subscript, eg:

```
<w:p>
  <w:pPr>
    <w:pStyle w:val="Normal"/>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:shd w:fill="auto" w:val="clear"/>
      <w:vertAlign w:val="subscript"/>
    </w:rPr>
  </w:pPr>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr/>
    <w:t>2</w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:shd w:fill="auto" w:val="clear"/>
      <w:vertAlign w:val="subscript"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>x</w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
```

To insert that xml inside your doc, you can use the docxtemplater cli (it is written in Node) https://github.com/open-xml-templating/docxtemplater (I'm maintaining this library)